# Iterate through vars without a index?

Tags: variables, for-loop, lua

I set some vars like this:

```
local var1Age = 10
local var2Age = 20
local var3Age = 30
```

Now I want to iterate them with a loop like this:

```
for i=1, 3 do
    if var..i..Age >= 21 then
        print("yep")
    end
end
```

I can't change the vars, or create a table instead. Is it possible somehow with this vars?

**Edit:**
I could do something like this:

```
if var1Age >= 21 then
    print("yep")
end
if var2Age >= 21 then
    print("yep")
end
if var3Age >= 21 then
    print("yep")
end
```

But I have ~50 vars like that. That's why I search a way to do it with a loop.

**Edit2:**
The vars are set by a class I can't change, so I can't change the way the vars are set.
For example I can't set the vars like this:

```
local varAge = {}
varAge[1] = 10
varAge[2] = 20
varAge[3] = 30
```

**Edit3:**
The class saves the vars in a table like this: http://ideone.com/iO4I8N

Comment: All those variables are local?

Comment: Yes. There set in the current scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the sample code you provided from your comment [here](http://ideone.com/iO4I8N), You should be able to iterate through your data structure without ever needing to use `debug.getlocal`.

```
local vars = varcount(DTClass)

for i = 1, vars do
  local vari = "var" .. i
  local variAge = DTClass[vari.."Age"]
  if variAge and variAge >= 21 then
    print(DTClass[vari.."Weight"])
  end
end
```

This should work whether `DTClass` is a table or a userdata assuming it provides a suitable `__index`. Of course you need some way to determine total elements in DTClass. Just implement the `varcount` function to do this.

If `DTClass` is a table, `varcount` can be as simple as `return #DTClass / var_fields`.

Comment: Never thought about that, but youre right! That's the best solution for my problem, thx ^^

Answer (score 5):

You could iterate through all local variables via `debug.getlocal` and filter variables you're interested in by name. http://www.lua.org/pil/23.1.1.html

Here is example on how to use it.

```
local var1Age = 10
local var2Age = 20
local var3Age = 30

function local_var_value(n)
    local a = 1
    while true do
        local name, value = debug.getlocal(2, a)
        if not name then break end
        if name == n then
            return value
        end
        a = a + 1
    end
end

for i=1, 3 do
    local v = local_var_value("var"..i.."Age")
    if v and v >= 21 then
        print("yep")
    end
end
```

Comment: That's not what I need. I know the vars, but cant change them.

Comment: Either your question doesn't describe what you "need", or you just haven't got that this function allows you do exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: I didn't tried it with var..i..Age, it will not point to the var1Age or will it? oO If yes, I answered my own question xD

Comment: input:6: attempt to concatenate global 'Age' (a nil value) Nope, I didn't.

Comment: Not that simple, but you have name of each variable. Now check if it matches 'var*Age' pattern and extract number from it.

Comment: @Fox, [debug.setlocal()](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/debug.setlocal) for changing?

Comment: @Fox not that much, see example.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I need. How about runtime? Are there any disadvantages using this instead of a lot of ifs?

Comment: Well, it could be _slow_ if you have _a_ _lot_ of local variables. And by this i mean really huge amount (i believe it will be something like tens of thousands). This method iterates through every local variable (O(N) complexity, where N is number of locals) instead of hash lookup via direct variable name (O(1) in long term). Difference is very unlikely to be noticable even with hundreds of locals.

Comment: Okay. I tried it with a table, as I want to use it. I tried it on ideone and get a success, but no output oO http://ideone.com/7gj9cm

Comment: @Fox it isn't local variables, it is a local table with your custom fields. Works as intended, it is a separate use case (much simpler than your original one)

Answer (score 4):

Are you really sure you want to stretch the language usage this far? The use of `debug` library should be left for advanced use when you cannot do otherwise.

Maybe your programming problem could be solved in a more elegant way using "regular" Lua facilities. To have a sequence of variables indexed by a number, simply use a table as an array:

```
local varAge = {}
varAge[1] = 10
varAge[2] = 20
varAge[3] = 30

for i=1,#varAge do
    if varAge[i] >= 21 then
        print("yep")
    end
end
```

**EDIT**

If you really need to use `debug.getlocal` and performance is really an issue, you can avoid the potential O(n<sup>2</sup>) behavior scanning the locals only once and storing their values in a table:

```
local var1Age = 10
local var2Age = 20
local var3Age = 30

local function GetLocalVars( level )
    local result = {}
    for i = 1, math.huge do
        local name, value = debug.getlocal( level, i )
        if not name then break end
        result[ name ] = value
    end
    return result
end

local local_vars = GetLocalVars( 2 )

for i = 1, 3 do
    local name = "var"..i.."Age"
    local v = local_vars[ name ]
    if v and v >= 21 then
        print("yep")
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm totally aware of this. But the vars are set by a class I can't change, so I have to access them like they are.

Comment: @Fox. OK. You really hit one of those advanced use I mentioned in my answer, then :-). Please consider adding this information (i.e. the context of usage) in your question, so that the problem appears with its full complexity to the next reader.

Comment: Can you show how that class is used that's generating these variable names?

Comment: @greatwold, I can't give the class a table if you mean that. I can give only a string and the var is called that way.

Comment: @Fox no, I mean show an actual minimal example of how you're getting those variables from the class. Add it to your question. We might be able to come up with other ideas.